# Determining cached rectangles in a matrix

Tags: javascript, caching, math, matrix, bitmap

Given a 2D sparse matrix like so:

```
. 2 3 . .
. 2 3 . .
. . . . .
```

Where `.` is an empty value.

Taking into account:

- The matrix is initially void of values but has a defined
  column and row count. The column and row count never changes.
- All selections from the matrix will be rectangular, and upon selection the fields become populated and should not be reselected.
- The matrix will only store numbers between 0 and 255 once populated, but the number bares no relation to the index (unlike the example).

So given the `3 x 5` matrix below:

```
. . . . .
. . . . .  
. . . . .
```

Select `2 x 2` from `[1, 0]`:

```
. 1 2 . .
. 1 2 . .
. . . . .
```

Select `2 x 3` from `[2, 1]`:

```
. 1 2 . .
. 1 2 3 4
. . 2 3 4
```

Is there a faster method to find whether or not a value is populated already, than looping through all of the values of the given rectangle to test them?

So that given my select `1 x 2` from `[2, 1]` I know I can just take the slice `2 3` without iterating the values?

I understand that iterating this matrix is not a problem but I intend to use this on matrices with matrices of 30,000+ cells, and large selection rectangles with a lot of overlapping.

Comment: Could you keep a sorted list of the rectangle start indeces and sizes in memory and figure it out that way? Sorry if you've considered this already, but it's not clear to me from your post.

Comment: @eigenchris Have considered this, don't be sorry it's useful to give some context. The problem is that this is a process that will happen many many times (this process is tied to mouse movement), and there will be a lot of overlapping rectangles (slight shifts), because there are many more possible rectangles than indices that is likely to be more expensive. As is computing when a rectangle has been absorbed by other rectangles on each change.

Comment: Alright. And just to make sure--are you just looking to see if an individual value is populated? Is accessing the matrix with the index of the mouse cursor to see if the entry is populated not an option?

Comment: @eigenchris Nope I'm looking to see which indices within a large rectangle aren't populated (likely breaking it into smaller rectangles). The mouse position doesn't actually match the location.

Comment: @eigenchris Perhaps you may be onto something though, it may be possible for me to merge then resplit the rectangles using https://nanoexplanations.wordpress.com/2011/12/02/polygon-rectangulation-part-1-minimum-number-of-rectangles/ to ensure they are minimal.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean now. That definitely looks like a helpful article. I'll post again if I have any insights.